# Which of these sentences is correct, or are they both?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Me and my sister are arguing over an English assignment. Can somebody say which of the following sentences is correct or if they both are?

> This has been proven obvious at the Colorado Center for Reproductive Medicine, where it is not uncommon for anticipating grandparents to come along and offer support and quite...

or

> At the Colorado Center for Reproductive Medicine it has been proven obvious that its not uncommon for anticipating grandparents to come along and offer support and quite...

Comment: I think the first one is correct.

Comment: First things first: use *expectant*, not *anticipating*. Now, the first version of your sentence leads in with *This*, which requires an antecedent in that position; given its weight, probably an immediate antecedent. Did the sentence preceding this one introduce an observation which this sentence is substantiating? Then use the first version of the sentence. If the preceding material did *not* already introduce such an observation, then use the second version of the sentence. Outside of all that, both these sentences have minor incongruencies which might be best explored at [ELL.se].

Comment: A good mnemonic, Lars, is "Jack and Jill anticipated marriage, and now Jill is expecting." Really dates me, doesn't it!

Comment: I would just like to point out that "proven obvious" is a self-contradiction. Obvious things do not _need_ to be proven, and generally _cannot_ be proven (e.g., my hand is obviously in front of my face, but I cannot prove it.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, but mean different things. Consider these simpler examples:

> This phenomenon has been observed in the atmosphere, where condensation almost always forms around dust particles.
>
> In the atmosphere, a phenomenon has been observed where condensation almost always forms around dust particles.

The first sentence refers to a phenomenon from the wider context, usually something that was previously described. The second sentence only makes a statement concerning what happens "in the atmosphere".

Likewise for your two sentences:

> This has been proven obvious at the Colorado Center for Reproductive Medicine, where it is not uncommon for expectant grandparents to come along and offer support and quite...
>
> At the Colorado Center for Reproductive Medicine it has been proven obvious that its not uncommon for expectant grandparents to come along and offer support and quite...

The first refers to something that was mentioned before and can be observed to hold true "at the Colorado Center", while the second only states something about "the Colorado Center".